# "am Computer" vs "im Computer"

Tags: preposition

How the meaning of this sentence changes if we substitute "am Computer" by "im Computer"

> Man könnte auch einfach darüber reden, dass das Problem nicht die Bundeswehr und Multiplayer-Taktikspiele **am Computer** sind, sondern die Drecksnazis, die ihr widerliches Gedankengut in die Welt hinaus blöken können, weil man die Schuld immer woanders sucht.

Thanks.

Comment: *am Computer* is a contraction of *die man am Computer spielt*, otherwise I would have chosen *auf dem Computer*, where the games are stored.

Comment: I love how this quote contradicts itself.

Comment: @Janka Depends on context ... what does *weil* refer to?

Comment: It's pretty obvious this person wants to blame *Drecksnazis, who speak up* for the ignorant actions of politicians, as e.g. “putting the gaming scene under observation”. This defies who's in charge, and it contradicts that last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`am` and `im` (contractions of `an dem` und `in dem`) in conjunction with an object ( material entity ) differ basically in denoting something *outside of* ( `am` ) vs. *inside* ( `im` ) that object.

The reading of the given sentence thus refers to the act of gaming ( multiplyer/tactics games ) with the computer. Replacing `am` by `im` would change the reading to the data files comprising the digital representation of the computer games as they are stored in memory or on hard disk. Figuratively that may extend to just 'whatever makes up a computer game so that we can play it at the computer`, ie. decoupling from representations or any other implied reference to technology.

So in summary, the sentence as given refers to the problem that people actually play certain games, while the `im` variant sees the problem in the availability of the games.

Comment: Very nice explanation!